# restrict access to AWS buckets in account while still allowing access to public buckets in other accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, public, bucket

For a given IAM user, I want to only allow that user access to one specific bucket in our account (call it `foo-bucket`).

However, this seems to have the effect of disabling access to any public bucket outside our account, which is not what I want. I'd like the user to still have access to any public bucket in another account, for example `broad-references`. I could of course explicitly grant access to a specific public bucket, but there are countless public buckets in the world and I don't want to restrict access to any of them.

Here is the existing policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "economycloud",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:Abort*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:RestoreObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListing",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone suggest an IAM policy that would do the following:

- Restrict access so that the user can only access this specific bucket in the account, as in the policy above, but
- Can access any public bucket in any other account.

Comment: Can you share your actual IAM policy for reference? (obviously without share the actual bucket name/account)

Comment: Just to clarify what you are asking, you want this user to have access to this ONE bucket, and access to any buckets that are public in the account?

Comment: Edited to respond to both comments.

Comment: I don't think this is actually possible, because there is no way to refer to "all S3 buckets in a specific account". Normally, this would be done via ARN wildcards, but it appears that an S3 ARN does not allow an account-id to be a wildcard.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying **this policy** has the effect of blocking access to other buckets?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it seems to.

Comment: That doesn't compute.  IAM `Allow` policies do not implicitly deny things not explicitly allowed.  I would suggest re-validating your current conclusions.  I'm not entirely sure that a "public" bucket is supposed to be accessible by an authenticated user without the user's account granting them permission to access it. [*"To perform a specific operation on a resource, an IAM principal needs permission from both the parent AWS account to which it belongs and the AWS account that owns the resource."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-s3-evaluates-access-control.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dan,

This is how you'll be able to achieve this:

- Explicitly Deny user's access to all the buckets in the [specific account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-1) except that specific bucket (foo-bucket).
- Explicitly Allow user's access to that specific bucket (foo-bucket).
- Explicit allow to the buckets from all accounts.

Comment: The first step seems very complex (we have hundreds of buckets in the account). The last step violates my last bullet point - the user should be able to access ANY public bucket in ANY account without the bucket having to be in the policy.

Comment: First step: you just need the account arn for which you've to deny access for the user.

Comment: Second step: you need to use wild card "*" in resource not the name of all buckets.